# How To Add IBM Maximo Websphere host to Windows Server Network Load Balance Cluster?

Tags: websphere, load-balancing, maximo, windows-server-2019

I'm beginner in Windows Serve Network Load Balance Tool, and I want to add IBM Maximo Instance that hosted on Websphere as a host in Windows Server NBL.

This is example of my ibm maximo domain: **http://10.0.0.11:9080/maximo**

I have tried several ways to do this approach but there is nothing i found.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: My understanding is that NLB only supports certain things, notably web applications running on IIS. I don't believe NLB would support third party application servers like WebSphere.

That said, WebSphere can be configured in a cluster without using NLB. Your best bet is to find documentation on this path.

Comment: Thanks Tim, i will try to find any documentation for this approach, if you have any documentation please tell me.

Comment: Take a look at the Installation Guide. This one is for Maximo 7.6. Chapter 5 covers deploying in a cluster: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLKT6_7.6.0/com.ibm.mam.doc/pdf_was_db2_tds_install.pdf